# Recommended lifetime for Azure Storage Clients?

Tags: azure-storage

What is the recommended lifetime for Azure Storage Clients like `CloudBlobClient`, `CloudQueueClient` and `CloudTableClient`?

I typically create one `CloudStorageAccount` which I pass around (through injection) -  Should I do the same with the e.g. a `CloudBlobClient` or should I create a new instance on each use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper CloudTableClient instance lifecycle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169539/proper-cloudtableclient-instance-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

I've just asked the same question an hour ago: [Proper CloudTableClient instance lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169539/proper-cloudtableclient-instance-lifecycle)

since *Client classes are not thread-safe, they should be instanciated for each request.